# Print every 6th and 7th lines

Tags: fortran

I want to a write a FORTRAN programming to read all the lines and I want to print every 7th and 8th lines  in output file from each set of data separated by blank line. I put a input file. Please hep me.

Thank you in advance!

```
 -4.164945E+05  3.001334E+02 -4.772577E+05  7.889016E+04 -5.561479E+05
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00 -4.088580E+05
  2.997668E+02  3.848513E+04 -1.806741E+06  5.561488E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  2.284295E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01
  0.000000E+00  5.478642E-01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  4.667412E-01 -2.655381E-01 -2.928033E-01 -2.655381E-01
  5.437324E-01  1.816853E-01 -2.928033E-01  1.816853E-01  6.331191E-01

 -4.165192E+05  3.002662E+02 -4.773093E+05  8.116229E+04 -5.584716E+05
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00 -4.012512E+05
  2.993096E+02  1.573615E+04 -1.839001E+06  5.584725E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  2.284295E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01
  0.000000E+00  1.095372E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  1.223969E+00 -2.234850E-04 -1.602426E-01 -2.234850E-04
  1.005241E+00  2.884689E-02 -1.602426E-01  2.884689E-02  1.056905E+00

 -4.165735E+05  3.013409E+02 -4.775812E+05  7.969518E+04 -5.572764E+05
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00 -4.067039E+05
  3.015952E+02  3.190769E+04 -1.818406E+06  5.572773E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  2.284295E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01
  0.000000E+00  7.080812E-01  1.157779E+00  1.385668E+00  5.455691E-01
  2.982146E-01  5.921261E-01  7.954344E-02  1.724112E-01  7.954344E-02
  7.981127E-01 -3.378208E-02  1.724112E-01 -3.378208E-02  7.340048E-01

 -4.165731E+05  2.994772E+02 -4.772035E+05  8.034912E+04 -5.575527E+05
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00 -4.041375E+05
  2.974779E+02  2.428109E+04 -1.827365E+06  5.575535E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  2.284295E+05  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01  9.000000E+01
  0.000000E+00  8.921716E-01  1.969410E+00  2.318855E+00  7.271637E-01
  6.363283E-01  7.974565E-01 -1.911601E-01 -9.800037E-02 -1.911601E-01
  7.979089E-01 -5.302858E-02 -9.800037E-02 -5.302858E-02  1.081150E+00
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: And is it 6th-7th or 7th-8th? Your title and text don't match.

Comment: I added an answer, but you really should have tried something first. Are you familiar with fortran?

Comment: Why do you want to use fortran for this anyway?

Comment: @Ross, I'm guessing the problem was *assigned* to OP. \*Nudge nudge wink wink\*

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your data all have 8 lines each with a single separator line, and up to 80 characters in a line, you could do

```
  character*80 :: inline
  integer      :: i, imod, stat

  open(1,file='infile')
  open(2,file='outfile',status='unknown')

  i = 0
  do
     i = i + 1
     read(1,'(80a)',iostat=stat) inline
     if (stat/=0) then !EOF reached
        exit
     end if 

     imod = mod(i-1,9) + 1
     if (imod>=7 .and. imod<=9) then
        write(2,*) inline
     end if
  end do
```

This will keep reading the input file line-by-line while counting the lines, until reaching an end-of-file (or other read error, to avoid an infinite loop). If the line number is congruent with 7-8-9 modulo 9, then it will print it (this will automatically keep the separator line as well).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!!! It is working. I just started learning FORTRAN ...I think I like it also.

Comment: @cjana, I'm glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as accepted. Also: fortran can be very cumbersome for many applications. Especially for file and string manipulation in this question, other, more modern languages can be far more useful.

Comment: @cjana, for instance, you could use an `awk` script to the same effect: `awk 'NR%9>=7 || NR%9==0' infile`. Although this takes into account that `mod(9,9)=0`, which we could've done in the fortran version too. But my point is, this is not an especially good field to use fortran for:)

Comment: Hi @Andras Desk, Sure! Thanks a lot!